# MVC 3 default document routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to make sure that when people goes to my domain eg. mydomain.com
they get referred to the home action in the home controller, eg mydomain.com/home/home.
I can't seem to make it work using the default document settings in the IIS.
I guess it has something to do with the global.asax but I haven't been successful in getting anything to work. I still just gets a 404 as it tried to find the view in /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In global.asax you need to set the correct default controller and action in your route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
    );
```

You would change action to "Home" instead of "Index".

Comment: Well that worked.. strange.. I had already tried that.. or so I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a Home method inside your HomeController

To get the default URL mapped to it, you need to edit your Global.asax.cs and change Index to Home. I.e.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: I have.. It works fine if you enter the complete url eg. mydomain.com/home/home.. but if you just enter mydomain.com you ofc get a 404. I need mydomain.com to point to mydomain.com/home/home

Answer (score 0):

You can default the site to land at Home/Home based on your mapped routes in Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {
      controller = "Home", // default controller when none is specified
      action = "Home",     // default action when none is specified
      id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }, // Parameter defaults
    new string[]{ "Web.Controllers" } // namespace
  );                                  // (helpful when you have separate views)
}
```